# Return both out value and query select value in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, plpgsql

Here is my sql server sample procedure while migrating to postgres sql i am unable to return output value and 
return query value.I want to return SUCCESS and followed by query value

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[VERIFY](
    @P_VER_NO VARCHAR(5) ,
    @P_SOLID VARCHAR(6) ,
    @P_ID VARCHAR(7) ,
    @P_MOBNO VARCHAR(15) ,
    @P_OUT_MSG VARCHAR(2) OUT 
    )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VOTP INT , @V_LNK INT ,@V_VERAVL VARCHAR(2) 
    IF @VOTP=0 
    BEGIN
      SELECT @P_OUT_MSG='SUCCESS'
      SELECT @P_OUT_MSG
      SELECT MCI.CHQ_MIN_LGTH AS MINCHEQUELENGTH,
        MCI.VRTL_CARD         AS VIRTUALCARD,

      FROM TRAN_TABLE  MCI  WITH(NOLOCK)
      WHERE MCI_SOLID=@P_SOLID;
      RETURN
    END
    ELSE 
    begin
     SELECT @P_OUT_MSG='FAILURE'
      SELECT @P_OUT_MSG
      SELECT MCI.ACCT_STAT AS MINCHEQUELENGTH,
        MCI.LOG_ATMPT         AS VIRTUALCARD,

      FROM TRAN_TABLE  MCI  WITH(NOLOCK)
      WHERE MCI_SOLID=@P_SOLID;
      RETURN
    end

END
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. You need to show your current attempts and any errors you get.

Comment: That code is not PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 0):

You should have two out argument one for success/failure, and other for the value.

Or you should not have an out argument for success/failure, but `RAISE ESCEPTION` on failure...